# Reducing the memory footprint of multiple Java processes on Solaris (UNIX)

Tags: java, memory, process, fork, shared-memory

Is there a way to have a Java process either fork or launch another Java process and use shared memory in order to minimize the RAM usage?

There will be many processes in order to allow one to be safely killed without affecting the others. Also this will allow simple detection of what threads are using more memory or CPU if they are in separate processes. This should allow any process to have a crash or OutOfMemoryError without affecting the other processes.

It would be nice if we could have 100-300 java processes running at the same time,, each with its own purpose. I realize we may have to limit that number and require processes to take on multiple roles if we are to keep from robbing too much memory from the database and filesystem.

**Edit:**
I think I hit an incorrect meaning when I said shared memory. What I mean is just memory that can be used among multiple processes like the Java classes (not the variables). All the java packages and libraries can be reused if possible.

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/vm/class-data-sharing.html

Comment: Thank you, This seems to be what I am looking for. Please move to an answer so I can accept. @Xepoch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@George Baily - Just caught your comment above.

Yes, newer JVMs do share class text, but as I understand it only in client (non-server) JVMs.  The benefit of this was reduced IO and startup time but has the added benefit in helping with a smaller footprint.

You can read more here:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/vm/class-data-sharing.html

You may also want to get aggressive on the heap resizing parameters as to allow for a smaller footprint.  Though semi-commercial, I maintain a small software package that manages workloads for multiple (hundreds) JVMs and dynamically manages OS-level IO and process priority to meet workload goals.  A poor-man's WLM for JVMs.  I've been unsuccessful thusfar in being able to manage the JVM ergonomics in runtime, but the WLM approach works surprisingly well.  Let me know if you want more info.

Comment: Following the doc, it generated shared archive (classes.jsa) using the -Xshare:dump in **server** JVM

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by shared memory?   Are you talking about the host system's memory?

Since you are using Solaris, Java threads are Solaris threads, and each thread gets its own process.  But Java still operates under the JVM memory parameters you give it.  If you get an OutOfMemoryError, the JVM's memory pool has reached its limit, not the host system.  In other words, in Java, you never really access shared memory -- that's the JVM's job.  If your Java processes need more memory, you have to raise the memory limit of the JVM.  But all that memory is managed by the JVM.  In order to truly access shared memory you would need to use JNI to get out of the JVM and into the host's memory.

If you are talking about a JVM launching another JVM, I suppose that is possible, but then you are talking about multiple JVM's, and to minimize RAM usage, each JVM should be given a really small initial pool of memory to work with.  Otherwise you have a bunch of JVM's taking up memory for their virtual memory models as well as for their associated threads.

Comment: This is a case when one JVM launches another. I am referring to Java core or anything that stays the same among the parent and child process or is initially the same but later some segments may be copied to process specific space if they need to change. I do not know what I am talking about. I just want to try and reduce RAM usage as much as possible. I am aware I will have to lock down the `-Xmx` to keep things reasonable. However, class storage (not variables) for things like MySQL connector, all the java packages; Java Mail, PDF Generator. These often would be used among multiple processes.

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't possible as far as I can tell. There are several reasons for this:

1. Ownership of shared objects would be a dubious affair, so the per-thread memory limit would be unenforceable.
2. If a thread dies, that's a serious problem. Threads don't die unexpectedly just like that, not if you install a catch-all exception handler. The only reason threads die unintentionally in a well-written system is if an `Error` is thrown, and that means that the system is unstable and usually also means that the VM should be stopped as quickly as possible.
3. Some very special cases aside (app/webservers in particular) It is unlikely that any system can carry on running after losing one of its threads. More often than not this could have dire consequences.

**Update:** Having found out that it is a webserver a solution is needed for, I'll try to go a bit further. Although Java was not designed for a level of isolation as high as you need. some of the functionality can be achieved by a [JVMTI](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jvmti/jvmti.html) agent. Specifically, threads can be [stopped](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jvmti/jvmti.html#StopThread), [objects reachable by a thread can be checked](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jvmti/jvmti.html#IterateOverObjectsReachableFromObject), [query the time used up by each thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jvmti/jvmti.html#GetThreadCpuTime) and so on. The bad news is that your agent will have to be written in C or something similar, it is notoriously hard to debug and any errors are likely to crash the virtual machine.

Comment: This is for a webapp server. Some webapps will be changed frequently in a production environment. As such there will inevitably be endless loops and memory overflows cause by faulty code. If that occurs it will have to be isolated from the rest of the threads - I expect this can only be fully achieved by separating processes. If necessary, existing threads in a process with an endless loop can finish and the webserver can know that is should not launch (a request for) any new threads on that process. Don't laugh at me for writing a new webserver. It has been very well thought through.

Comment: @George Bailey Why would I laugh? I'll update my answer instead.